# error on truncated rms

Tags: standard-error, descriptive-statistics, truncation, rms, coverage-probability

I am computing the RMS of a sample to estimate the standar error $\sigma$ of the underlying distribution (for simplicity let say a normal distribution $N[\mu$, $\sigma$]).

$ \text{RMS} = \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar x)^2 / (N-1)$

I am using a truncated version of the RMS to avoid outliers in the population. I am considering only the $x_i$ inside the smallest range $I$ contanting a fraction $f$ of the total sample (for example $f=90\%$).

$ \text{RMS'} = \sum_{x_i\in I} (x_i - \bar x)^2 / N'\quad\text{with}\quad N' = Nf \qquad \text{(let forget the -1)}$

Now $\text{RMS'}$ is biased, but it is quite easy to fix it, multiplying it by a constant $\alpha$ which depend only on $f$ (see [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/wiso/bbb0f470668e3ae30859))

The question is: what is the error on $\text{RMS}'$? For example I have computed the error on $\text{RMS}$ from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance) and using $\text{RMS} = \sqrt{s}$:

$\text{error on RMS}=\text{RMS} / \sqrt{2  N}$

I expected so:

$\text{error on RMS'}=\alpha \text{RMS'} / \sqrt{2  N'}$

but it seems to don't have good coverage (to cover 68% of the times the true value $\sigma$).